# Django Rest Framework Angulars upload file using ModelSerializer

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, upload

I'm trying to upload an image using Django Rest Framework and AngularJs
I'm using ng-file-upload to upload the image with AngularJs.

I saw it's possible to use ApiViewSet to do this. But as my Image is in a model and I use ModelSerializer so if it's possible I prefer to use ModelViewSet.

The problem is when I upload the image I got an error:

```
image: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

Here is my code

Models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to="articles")
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

Serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       #article = ArticleSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
       image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True, allow_empty_file=True)
       model = Image

       fields = ('id', 'image', 'article')
       read_only_fields = ('id', )

#def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
#    exclusions = super(ImageSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusion()

#   return exclusions + ['article']
```

Views.py

```
class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Image.objects.order_by('id')
serializer_class = ImageSerializer

class ImageArticleViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Image.objects.select_related('article').all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, image_pk=None):
       queryset = self.queryset.filter(article__id=image_pk)
       serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)

       return Response(serializer.data)
```

And the Controller

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module(nameProject + '.article.post.controller')
    .controller('ArticlePostController', ArticlePostController);

ArticlePostController.$inject = ["$scope", "Articles", "Upload", "$timeout"];

function ArticlePostController($scope, Articles, Upload, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.postArticle = postArticle;


    $scope.$watch('files', function () {

        $scope.upload($scope.files);
        console.debug("files = ", $scope.files);
        //console.debug("upload = ", $scope.upload);

    });

    $scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                console.debug("file = ", file, "type = ", file.type);

                Upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/v1/images/',
                    fields: {
                        'idArticle': 1,
                        'article': 1,
                        'image': file
                    },
                    file: file,
                    image:file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
                    evt.config.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $timeout(function () {

                        console.log("data === ", data.result);

                        $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;


                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };




}
})();
```

And this line

```
console.debug("files = ", $scope.files);
```

prints in the console

```
type =  image/jpeg
```

The Jade template

```
form.form-signin(ng-submit="vm.postArticle()" enctype="multipart/form-data")
h2.form-signin-heading Post un article
    input.input-block-level(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Title" ng-model="vm.title")
    input.input-block-level(type="number", name="price", placeholder="Price" ng-model="vm.price")
    input.input-block-level(type="text", name="content", placeholder="Description" ng-model="vm.description")
    input.input-block-level(type="number", name="quantity", placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="vm.quantity")
    input.input-block-level(type="text", name="color", placeholder="Color" ng-model="vm.color")
    input.input-block-level(type="text", name="state", placeholder="State" ng-model="vm.state")
    input.input-block-level(type="number", name="year", placeholder="Year" ng-model="vm.year")
    p watching model
    div(class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="multiple") Select File on file change:
    button.btn.btn-large.btn-primary(type="submit") Submit article
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's REST Framework default way of dealing with uploaded files is to examine the header and decide how to deal with it:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

By default ng-file-upload, uploads the file in `json` format, this means that the file you are uploading is submitted as Base64 to Django, which in turn will try to decode the file using the following:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser

This does not work with the default Django File field, there are different ways to accomplish this, one is to use the following option (`sendFieldAs`) in your request:

```
Upload.upload({
    url: '/api/v1/images/',
    ...
    sendFieldsAs: form,
```

This will submitt the data as a form, which Django REST framework will process as it should. The other options, would include decoding the Base64 and manually creating the File to be used with the file field, something that adds overhead compared to the `sendFieldAs` option.

Comment: I tried the first solution   `sendFieldsAs: "form"`
And I got  `image: ["No file was submitted."]`
I'll use FileUploadParser